# To import AWS cli json output into a dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am creating a script to get some details from different AWS resources. The AWS-cli commands returns a json output like below (output of 7 days CPU utilisation of ec2 instances) -:

```
    {
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2021-12-10T16:18:00+00:00",
            "Average": 0.10045197740112988,
            "Unit": "Percent"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2021-12-10T16:18:00+00:00",
            "Average": 0.12184103236292673,
            "Unit": "Percent"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way that i can import this data to a dashboard where i can visualize these values ?

If not directly to dashboard then what is the correct way of achieving this "display via dashboard" thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **Amazon CloudWatch dashboards**, which are built exactly for monitoring these sorts of metrics.

> Amazon CloudWatch dashboards are customizable home pages in the CloudWatch console that you can use to monitor your resources in a single view, even those resources that are spread across different Regions.
>
> You can use CloudWatch dashboards to create customized views of the metrics and alarms for your AWS resources.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Dashboards.html) will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

go with couldwatch metric API, using simple REST call you will get the data. please refer below doc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

sample doc for put data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html

hope this will help you to start.

Comment: I don't want to do it with cloudwatch, i am self calling the resource details via aws cli and then want to display data on a dashboard. Like i am creating my custom aws billing dashboard.

Comment: in any case you need to publish  service to consume the data. either you import the data using cloudwatch API or write your own service to consume the data using some script, basically you need to a new service in place to pull the data or data get push by other system.

Comment: I am using aws cli commands to pull data via cloudwatch metrics to which i am getting required json output as above .. but need to display this data to any dashboard or something .. how to do that .. is there any dashboard to which i can upload this json file and get the display ?

Comment: I have json output coming out from my script, basically i want to display this data into a dashboard i guess the json data need to be inserted into a database and then i can stream this data to a dashboard with my database as datasource.

Comment: @an please go for cloudWatch dashboard.